# How to recover a dropped MongoDB database?

Tags: mongodb, database

If somebody accidentally dropped a MongoDB database but executing db.dropDatabase(), how can he recover the database?

Dropping a database in MongoDB is simple, and the command db.dropDatabase() won't erase all the data on it but marks it as to be deleted, so the size of the database would not change after using the drop command, which I think there should be some way to remove the to-be-deleted marker. Can some one point me how?

Comment: Dropping a database is a destructive operation --- there is no undelete button. You should make sure you take backups regularly and restore from those as your "Recovery".

Comment: @Blackmoon, maybe imcoddy is just asking the question out of curiosity.

Comment: @TTT thanks, I actually wanted to ask how to recovered a MongoDB database after executing the db.dropDatabase() command, maybe my question was specific enough...

Comment: It is a really good question! And nobody was able to answer so far now!

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli I tried to reproduce the situation and posted an answer.

Answer (score 7):

I tried to reproduce what you had done. I killed a database using db.dropDatabase() after I had backed it up :-) The db name was 'gacheater'. Before dropping mongodb folder contained 3 files (the db is non-empty):

- gacheater.ns
- gacheater.1
- gacheater.2

after dropping these files disappeared. Therefore I think *mongodb really removes your data*.

So the only choice you have is to try to restore files from the filesystem

PS: MacOS 10.5, MongoDB 1.8.2

Comment: those are the DB-files - and yes, MongoDB deletes the DB files - there is no "undo", unless you have a DB backup

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK most systems just mark the file as deleted, via a flag rather than actually overwriting it. It's possible to recover files with standard tools...

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linuxunix-recover-deleted-files.html

These might be easier to work with

http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/

As pointed out no substitute for backups.