# Is it possible to undo a drop operation on a Mongo Collection?

Tags: mongodb

I have a standalone setup of MongoDB 2.0.2 with default settings. I accidently dropped a collection from the shell using `db.mycollection.drop()` . Is there anyway I can undo this operation and rollback to previous state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a stand alone (no replicaset) I am afraid that you may not be able to recover your data. Read this post [How to recover a dropped MongoDB database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619438/how-to-recover-a-dropped-mongodb-database)

Comment: I read that post. I deleted collection as opposed to Database. I am hoping I can recover it. The thing is the size of the data files hasn't changed much. Perhaps there is a way to process it and revert back to an older state? I don't know but I wish there was

Comment: @nadirsaghar What OS is it? Most OS' will just mark the information as deleted which means you might be able to use recovery programs to get the data back

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention it, the same logic applies to collection unless it has been changed in recent releases of mongodb. db.collection.drop() and db.dropDatabase() are irreversible as explained in this other link: http://www.markus-gattol.name/ws/mongodb.html . To quickly get info on that page, search for "Delete a Collection". If you are doing tests on a production database, set up a replicaset with slavedelay if you think that it can happen again.